# How to change an existing folder permissions with VS2013 msi deployment?

Tags: windows-installer, folder-permissions

It's my first time developing an msi deployment package. All I need to do is change a specific folder permissions to allow the group 'Everyone' to 'Full control'.

I've already searched the web and SO, but nothing seems to help. Is there an easy step-by-step solution?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard Visual Studio setup project, there is no built in support for this. You'd have to ask in a forum related to security what the code would be. Or figure out how to use the poorly documented LockPermissions table in the MSI file by editing with Orca.

Many times this question is asked it's because the application is installed into a restricted folder like the ProgramFiles folder, and it creates or updates files in that location. If that's the reason for this question then the correct way to deal with that is to change the app to use a location such as the User's Application Data folder, which, as it name implies, is where you store and update the user's data :)